# Ionic 3 - Pushing a page makes the browser refresh and navigates to the home page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

My problem is: I simply push a signin page through my login page. It is a very simple thing, BUT, when I click on my link, I see the signin view for 0.5 seconds, and my browser refreshes and go back to the login view...

(I'm using Ionic 3.)

As simple code as possible:

```
<a class="light center" href="" (click)="pushSignInPage()"><i>J'ai déjà un compte</i></a>

pushSignInPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(SignInPage);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm assuming you're using Angular 2 since you're using Ionic 3. When trying to send to another page I usually use [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Comment: Hi ! Not sure but i will check, another thing, i just test to create an other button to push my tabs view (from tabs ionic template) and it s work...

Comment: Hmm you can use ionic tabs as well. Here I leave you an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3tabs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.

Never use the <a> tag to push a view again <3.